# Создать столбец согласно значениям строк

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, numpy

Есть DataFrame, в нем есть столбцы budget и gross.

Разницу между столбцами прописал в отдельную колонку так:

```
df['revenue'] = df['gross']-df['budget']
```

**Получил**:

```
df.revenue.head()

0    523505847.0
1      9404152.0
2    -44925825.0
3    198130642.0
5   -190641321.0
Name: revenue, dtype: float64
```

Как видно в столбце есть минусовые значения т.е. убыточные проекты.

Задача добавить в DataFrame столбец с выставленными значениями, если значение revenue имеет минус, значит 1, если нет = 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [np.where(...)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['new'] = np.where(df['revenue'] < 0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Супер. Спасибо !

Comment: @FaridunIsmoilzoda, пожалуйста :)